# Cannot add with Hibernate BigDecimal (SQLite)

Tags: java, hibernate

When I'm trying to add Object with field BigDecimal (new BigDecimal("1.0")) I'm getting this error:

> 16:00:59.058 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver [n/a] java.sql.SQLException: not
>   implemented by SQLite JDBC driver     at
>   org.sqlite.Unused.unused(Unused.java:29) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar:na]
>     at org.sqlite.Unused.setBigDecimal(Unused.java:58)
>   ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar:na]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_38]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_38]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_38]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_38]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]     at
>   $Proxy20.setBigDecimal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]   at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DecimalTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(DecimalTypeDescriptor.java:58)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:92)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:305)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:57)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2602)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2579)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2760)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:60)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2767)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3278)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:728)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:720)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:409)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:350)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:448)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:728)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:720)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:409)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:350)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:448)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:728)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:720)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:409)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:350)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:448)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:757)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:749)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
>   [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]  at
>   database.sqlite.sessionsworkers.InsertSessionWorker.applyOnDatabase(InsertSessionWorker.java:25)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   database.sqlite.sessionsworkers.InsertSessionWorker.applyOnDatabase(InsertSessionWorker.java:1)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   database.local.sqlite.SQLite.doTransaction(SQLite.java:108)
>   [classes/:na]     at database.local.sqlite.SQLite.save(SQLite.java:137)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   database.local.sqlite.SQLite.saveOwner(SQLite.java:173) [classes/:na]
>     at
>   database.local.sqlite.SQLiteTest.create_database(SQLiteTest.java:67)
>   [test-classes/:na]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_38]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_38]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_38]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_38]    at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
>   [junit-4.10.jar:na]   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>   [.cp/:na]     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   [.cp/:na]

Comment: from the error "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver" - so presumably SQLLite doesn't support that datatype. Maybe impelement a `UserType` and save it as a `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the error "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver" - so presumably SQLLite doesn't support that data type.
Maybe implement a `UserType` and save it as a `String`?

```
public class BigDecimalToStringType implements UserType {

    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = {Types.VARCHAR};

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Class<BigDecimal> returnedClass() {
        return BigDecimal.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet resultSet, final String[] names, final SessionImplementor si, final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        final String value = StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeGet(resultSet, names[0], si);
        if (value != null) {
            return new BigDecimal(value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement preparedStatement, final Object value, final int index, final SessionImplementor si) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (null == value) {
            preparedStatement.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, ((BigDecimal) value).toPlainString(), index, si);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(final Serializable cached, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(final Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) throws HibernateException {
        if (x == y) {
            return true;
        }
        if (null == x || null == y) {
            return false;
        }
        return x.equals(y);
    }
}
```

Not fast but you won't lose precision. By default hibernate makes a `VARCHAR(255)` so you may want to make this longer.
You will need to specify this in your hibernate mappings thus:

```
<property name="myValuePropertyName" type="com.my.package.name.BigDecimalToStringType"/>
```

And then hibernate will use that to persist the data.
Maybe some kind soul with `JPA` knowledge will give you the equivalent annotations...

Comment: Unfortunately, using a `String` instead of a `BigDecimal` can lead to wrong results in some cases: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issue/114/incorrect-binding-of-bigdecimal-values-as

Comment: @LukasEder are you sure this is applicable to Hibernate? This bug is registered against Xerial.

Answer (score 2):

@Boris the Spider
In annotations you can wrtite

```
@Type (type="utils.BigDecimalToStringType")
private BigDecimal bigDecimal;
```

(I can not post comments, because I have to low reputation)

PS 
I don't know why you have abstract there.

Comment: Unfortunately, using a `String` instead of a `BigDecimal` can lead to wrong results in some cases: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issue/114/incorrect-binding-of-bigdecimal-values-as